# Download file from Artifact Registry (Maven)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, gzip, repository, maven

I have been playing with REST API for Artifact Registry. I can find the URL for .zip files I would like to download, but I only get JSON responses. Is it possible to download individual artifact files from the Artifact Registry with Maven projects?

Source: [Method: projects.locations.repositories.files.get](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/projects.locations.repositories.files/get)

For now it seems like I would need to use `mvn` and `gradle` to do this which would be inconvenient in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it described in the [Artifact Registry API docs](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/projects.locations.repositories.files/get) you mentioned, the files received by using the `get` method are represented in JSON.

You would need to use Maven or Gradle indeed to [download an artifact](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/java/manage-packages#download).

As @IanW mentioned, there are two feature requests you can upvote:

- [Artefact Download button in GAR console](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/225186486)
- [Download file from Artifact Registry (Maven)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203557347)

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicion and the link to feature request page. Will surly post that.

Comment: There are 2 feature requests that I'd encourage everyone to star or +1: one for a UI download option: [225186486 - Artefact Download button in GAR console](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/225186486) and one for a REST/Curl option: [203557347 - Download file from Artifact Registry (Maven)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203557347) (may have been submitted by the OP)

Comment: @Farid-Shumbar, would you care to update your answer with the links from my comment ?